# Accuracy and Recall is the same for resnet implementation pytorch

Tags: scikit-learn, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, resnet

I have used accuracy_score and recall_score from sklearn.metrics to calculate the scores, but no matter what epoch it is, both the accuracy and recall are coming up as the same value for CIFAR100 dataset. I am trying to implement it in Pytorch. Sample y_pred, y_true that I am passing to the function look like `y_pred = [11, 12, 65, ..... 13, 15, 17]` and `y_true = [11, 12, 53, ..... 13, 78, 17]`. Can you suggest where I might be going wrong?

Comment: Is the model learning, i.e. loss is decreasing?

Comment: Yes and accuracy is also increasing.